# how does cross-env command works in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, cross-env

I have the following line in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js"
}
```

I can see that "**yarn start**" command is running fine, but when I run
"**cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js**" command directly in the terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: cross-env
```

If cross-env is not registered in the terminal, how does "**yarn start**" command works?

Comment: Because you have it installed in node_modules. If you want to use it outside, you would need to do `npm install --global cross-env` to use it anywhere. Just because you're cd'd n the project does not mean you will be able to use commands inside `node_modules`. `./node_modules/.bin/cross-env` should also work.

Comment: I get that, then why does "yarn start" command work? My understanding is "yarn start" just runs the "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js" command in terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders#executables

> When in local mode, executables are linked into ./node_modules/.bin so that they can be made available to scripts run through npm. (For example, so that a test runner will be in the path when you run npm test.)

It's simply a feature to make things easier. It also means if you're working a project with multiple people, you only have to `npm install --save` a module--you don't have to worry about everyone in your project manually installing it globally. If you wish to run it yourself on the command line, you can either:

- Install the module globally
- Manually type in the command line `./node_modules/.bin/cross-env`
- Install npx and use `npx cross-env`

Comment: Use `npx`! Don't dig into node_modules yourself

Answer (score 0):

So, I see that people have informed you that `yarn` pulls `cross-env` from the local project's `node_modules` directory.

In addition to installing `cross-env` globally (`npm install --global cross-env`) so that you can run `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js` in your terminal, you can also use `npx` to run it:

```
npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js
```

> **How does `npx` work?** 
> When you use `npx`, it first checks if the required package is already
> installed locally in the `node_modules` folder of your current project.
> If the package is not found, `npx` downloads the package from the npm
> registry and stores it temporarily in a cache folder specific to `npx`.